# Android Studio Onclick and fragment does not work

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio, onclicklistener

When I click on my Travel button it should replace the Menufragment with the TravelFragment. But for some reason it doesnt work and I dont know if the issue is from the onClicklistener or the way i replace fragments. And when I debug it complains in line 32, "View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false);" is the code I have.

```
    import android.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MenuFragment extends Fragment {


       public MenuFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false);
    Button TravelButton = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.travel);

    TravelButton.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);

    return root;
}
private View.OnClickListener buttonListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId() ){
            case R.id.travel:{
                TravelFragment newFragment = new TravelFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.container, newFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

}

And this is my xml code for my mainactivity (The FrameLayout is inside a RelativeLayout for containing the container where I can replace fragments for example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I cant find the problem. Please help. Im new to Android Studio so be patient with me! All help is welcome.

Comment: What does the debugger/IDE complain about your line 32?

Comment: It doesnt specify any problem. Only shows a which line of code so I can go there. Then in the debugger it show a red text which contains: 5467-5467/se.sneineh.appforduaa A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x000035a0 (code=1), thread 5467 (ineh.appforduaa)

Comment: I maybe forgot to say, what happens is that the app crashes when i click on the button. The button is like keeping beeing blue, then crashes. Nothing else happens.

Comment: SIGSEGV is from some native code. I just googled a bit and it seems it could be caused by out-of-memory errors. If you could post the output from your debugger (the red text) that would be more helpful.

Comment: Thats the only red text (output) I get. The one I posted above..

Comment: 7497-7497/se.sneineh.appforduaa E/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Out of memory on a 46564288-byte allocation.

Comment: Could this be a problem from my device, or its something from the application?

Comment: So it's indeed out-of-memory error. If you application does use a lot of memory and you run it through a simulator you would need to increase the virtual device's memory. Otherwise you need to check your code for errors such as memory leaks, infinite loops etc.

Comment: Since its in my begining phase of this application I dont have much code yet, and no loops initialized yet. The code you see above is the only code so far I´ve added. Then it must be from my device (Phone).

Comment: After some changes.. It works now. I had a imagebutton and an audio.. When i deleted these, it worked.. Do you know how i can increase the limit of usage?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code by adapting it:

```
frag_results frag_results = new frag_results();
                    FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.framelayout_secundary, frag_results, frag_results.getTag()).commit();
```